# Custom DPI settings in KDE

Tags: 11.04, fonts, kde, kubuntu, dpi

How can I set a **custom value for font DPI in KDE?**

The **only** options **available in KDE** are **96 and 120 DPI** values. My Screen resolution is 1920*1080, so I would like to keep the **DPI at a value higher than 120**.

I know how to do this in gnome.
 *Could any one tell how to set custom DPI values in KDE?*

**A GUI method is preferred**

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the actual screen DPI? If you disable the "force font dpi" it should use your screen's DPI and therefore have the best rendering of the fonts. If you want to change the font size, change the font size directly.  If your screen's DPI is incorrectly detected, you can use xrandr to set the correct DPI in your kdm startup https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_commands_in_kdm.2BAC8-gdm_startup_scripts

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find and change the screen DPI?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi)

Comment: @Sneetsher this question is specific to KDE. The other question that you linked is generic ubuntu.

Comment: @AIB, I thought this is an old question which didn't get an accepted answer, where `xrandr` could be the solution. didn't work? Could I ask if you found other working solution?

Comment: BTW @AIB, it's for 11.04 :) I preferred closing it as duplicate then off-topic.

Comment: You can edit these numbers

Answer (score 3):

Just go to *System Settings > Application Appearance > Fonts*, and manually enter the dpi value you would like. No need to change `fonts.conf`.

Incidentally, most desktop environments have a GUI way to change this. Even lightweights like XFCE have it.

Comment: With the new plasma this is _System Settings_ > _Fonts_

Answer (score 2):

Configuration can be done per-user through ~/.fonts.conf, and globally with /etc/fonts/local.conf. The settings in the per-user configuration have precedence over the global configuration. Both these files use the same syntax.

Just scroll down and change the DPI value in the conf file. You may have to restart x or logout/login to KDE to get the change to apply.

This applies to most DEs, I don't know of any GUI method to do it other than what you have tried already.

[font config man page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html)!