# How do I change the DPI settings in terminal?

Tags: dpi

I accidentally made my DPI settings really really large and now I can't change them back to a smaller setting because it's so large that it's not visible on my screen to fix it. Is there a way to correct DPI settings in the Command Line???

edit: Font DPI

Comment: you will find your answer in this thread :

[how to change dpi in terminal][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi

Answer (score 1):

To change the Font DPI in the terminal (default is 1.0)

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0`

If you are talking about changing the screen DPI then you can follow the directions for:

[How to find and change the screen DPI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux Mate DE, this worked for me:

```bsh
dconf write "/org/mate/desktop/font-rendering/dpi" "132.0"
```

The decimal place is very important, for some reason it won't work without it. It will set it to default value.

Also if you wanna read the existing values:

```bsh
dconf read "/org/mate/desktop/font-rendering/dpi"
dconf list "/org/mate/desktop/font-rendering/"
```