# Ubuntu and full hd display

Tags: 13.04, resolution, appearance

I recently bought a new 14 inch laptop with full hd screen. As I was expecting after installing windows 8 and ubuntu 13.04 all icons and fonts were rather small and uncomfortable. In windows 8 I found one simple solution - right click on desktop, then click on Personalize, then click on Display. After that you will be presented with option called Change the size of all items. Here you can easily increase the size of everything in one click, it is rather nice.

In ubuntu I installed unity tweak but there everything is separated. In one place I can increase font size in the other place I can increase icons of launcher. So everything is not coordinated.

Guys, do you know if ubuntu has some mechanism which will allow me increase the size of everything like in windows 8?

Comment: This might be a duplicate to this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi).

Comment: Use the displays settings. If you are using proprietary drivers for your graphics card, then there are normally management tools included, or available. For eg. my AMD card  has the Catalyst application where I can set the resolution and other things. Saurav's post below show how to use the display tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good solution, but have you tried setting the resolution lower?  I had the same issue and I ended up setting the screen resolution to 1360x768 (from 1920x1080).  You can change the resolution by going to **System Setting** -> **Displays** -> **Resolution**.

That way everything is bigger, including the headers on the windows, the top panel, the cursor, the sizes of buttons inside applications (such as Firefox, LibreOffice), etc.