# Reducing Ubuntu screen DPI

Tags: unity, 13.04

First of I apologize if this is a duplicate thread, I tried searching to no avail.

I'm currently looking to reduce the entire system DPI in Ubuntu 13.04
I work better with multiple windows and the default DPI for my laptop is a little to big.

Comment: Did you try [these instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi)?

Comment: Yes I have but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you please go a little more in-depth what exactly you have tried and what the result was?

Comment: I have tried the methods that were listed there. I have tried editing lightdm.conf and adding xserver-command=X -dpi 80 (my default is 96) and there is no change.

I have tried the second method of creating a file called 77set_dpi and adding xrandr --dpi 80x80 and moving it to the directory it asked me to. Restarted and no difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new setting in Ubuntu 14.04 to set global DPI scaling:

[see this Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/462023/294881)