# How to get the right DPI resolution on Ubuntu 13.04 Saucy?

Tags: xorg, resolution, lightdm, dpi

The physical DPI of my laptop screen is approximately 142 dots per inch as you can calculate from the *correct* output of `xrandr --query`:

```
$ xrandr --query | head
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
```

However, Ubuntu appearantly forces the X server to use 96 dpi and thus assume a wrong physical size of the display, which you can check with `xdpyinfo`

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep -B2 dots
screen #0:
  dimensions:    1920x1080 pixels (508x286 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

As a consequence, fonts and other visual elements are smaller as they should be. You can check with any web browser [on this website](http://www.infobyip.com/detectmonitordpi.php). The square is too small, less than 1 in^2.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/272172) lists a number of work-arounds, none of which works for me:

1. Tell lightdm to start X with the option `-dpi 142`, which I achieved on Saucy by editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf. Has no effect.
2. Run `xrandr -dpi 142x142`, when starting the X session by adding a file to /etc/X11/Xsession.d/. Has no effect
3. Set the text-scaling-factor, which can be achieved in a number of ways. This only effects fonts rendered by Unity/Gnome/GTK(?), basically the standard Ubuntu GUI, but fails for other apps such as web browsers or PDF viewers. Not what I want.

How do I get Ubuntu to use the correct dpi for my screen?

**Update:** This appears to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/589485) disguised as a feature. What are your workarounds?

Answer (score 7):

To get current DPI resolution use

```
xdpyinfo | grep -B2 resolution
```

To update DPI resolution say to 142 dpi use

```
xrandr --dpi 142
```

Answer (score 0):

I have install packet tracer and the variable QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO has defined :

```
# echo $QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO
auto
```

i have comment in /etc/profile file :

```
#QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=auto
#export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO
```

it's ok now