# How can I get my laptop's monitor size?

Tags: monitor

What is the Ubuntu linux command to find laptop monitor size? I want to know in inches if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Hi user111, please see this: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15051/72216. Could you at least provide *some* feedback?

Answer (score 69):

Another option, using `xrandr`, is the command:

```
xrandr | grep ' connected'
```

Output:

```
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
VGA-1 connected 1280x1024+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
```

*(mind the space before `connected`, else `disconnected` will be included)*

#### Important differences between `xdpyinfo` and `xrandr`

- While `xrandr` lists screens separately (in case of multiple monitors), `xdpyinfo` outputs one single set of dimensions for all screens together ("desktop size" instead of screen size)
- As noticed by @agold there is (quite) a difference between the two, which seems too big to be a simple rounding difference:

  ```
  xrandr: 473mm x 296mm
  xdpyinfo: 445x278
  ```

It seems related to [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/201491) in `xdpyinfo`. See also [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204823).

#### If you'd insist on inches

Use the small script below; it outputs the size of your screen(s) in inches; width / height / diagonal (inches)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
# change the round factor if you like
r = 1

screens = [l.split()[-3:] for l in subprocess.check_output(
    ["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").strip().splitlines() if " connected" in l]

for s in screens:
    w = float(s[0].replace("mm", "")); h = float(s[2].replace("mm", "")); d = ((w**2)+(h**2))**(0.5)
    print([round(n/25.4, r) for n in [w, h, d]])
```

#### To use it:

Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `get_dimensions.py`, run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/get_dimensions.py
```

Output on my two screens:

```
width - height - diagonal (inches)

[18.6, 11.7, 22.0]
[14.8, 11.9, 19.0]
```

---

#### Edit

*Fancy* version of the same script (with a few improvements and a nicer output), looking like:

```
Screen  width   height  diagonal
--------------------------------
DVI-I-1 18.6    11.7    22.0
VGA-1   14.8    11.9    19.0
```

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
# change the round factor if you like
r = 1

screens = [l.split() for l in subprocess.check_output(
    ["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").strip().splitlines() if " connected" in l]

scr_data = []
for s in screens:
    try:
        scr_data.append((
            s[0],
            float(s[-3].replace("mm", "")),
            float(s[-1].replace("mm", ""))
            ))
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(("\t").join(["Screen", "width", "height", "diagonal\n"+32*"-"]))
for s in scr_data:
    scr = s[0]; w = s[1]/25.4; h = s[2]/25.4; d = ((w**2)+(h**2))**(0.5)
    print(("\t").join([scr]+[str(round(n, 1)) for n in [w, h, d]]))
```

---

### EDIT 2 (May 2019)

"Kind of" on request (in a comment), a modernized / more advanced / improved (no system calls, no parsing but using Gdk.Display) version, doing pretty much exactly the same:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk

dsp = Gdk.Display.get_default()
n_mons = dsp.get_n_monitors()

print(("\t").join(["Screen", "width", "height", "diagonal\n"+32*"-"]))

for i in range(n_mons):
    mon = dsp.get_monitor(i)
    mon_name = mon.get_model()
    w = mon.get_width_mm()/25.4
    h = mon.get_height_mm()/25.4
    d = ((w**2)+(h**2))**(0.5)
    print(("\t").join([mon_name]+[str(round(n, 1)) for n in [w, h, d]]))
```

*Output:*

```
Screen  width   height  diagonal
--------------------------------
eDP-1   20.0    11.3    23.0
HDMI-1  18.6    11.7    22.0
```

I will leave the original answer, since it seems inappropriate to remove the answer after such a long time, that generated the existing votes.

Comment: Just a side note, but both answers give me different results: `xdpyinfo` gives me "474x303 millimeters", and `xrandr` "473mm x 296mm".

Comment: @agold Now that is interesting. A rounding difference. Another interesting thing is that `xdpyinfo` outputs the *desktop* size (both screens), not the screen's size!

Comment: @agold the difference is way too big for a rounding difference!! See my edit.

Comment: yes, it is quite big, but how do these programs get this information? Is it some meta information coming from the monitor, or is it estimated based on some other parameters...?

Comment: @agold It seems to be related to a bug in `xdpyinfo`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/201491 ALthough the report is quite old, I don't see it fixed. Also see: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204823

Comment: Good find! So I guess xrandr should be used then.

Comment: It is actually a "bug" in X itself, where the DPI of the screen is set to 96x96 in lieu of actual DPI. Xdpyinfo only gets its info from X, xrandr is querying the screens directly.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./size.py", line 10, in <module>
    w = float(s[0].replace("mm", "")); h = float(s[2].replace("mm", "")); d = ((w**2)+(h**2))**(0.5)```

This is an error from the 1st python script.

Comment: @AleksandrRyabov Can't reproduce it, but please mention the full message: the error is missing.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, this is a full error:
```$ ./size.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./size.py", line 10, in <module>
    w = float(s[0].replace("mm", "")); h = float(s[2].replace("mm", "")); d = ((w**2)+(h**2))**(0.5)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'axis'```

The script that you showed in the first sample.

Comment: Unfortunately I think xrandr is buggy. my external 37.5" ultrawide monitor is shown as a 255mm x 255mm monitor, 10"x10" with the python script:
DP-1-1 connected primary 3840x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 255mm x 255mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   3840x1600     30.00*

Comment: @aless80 See updated answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sorry to disappoint you but I still see a 10"x10" monitor. I am using a laptop with ultrawide monitor. the laptop is off. I tried xdpyinfo and at least it gave me a more reasonable value in my configuration, but when I disconnect the external monitor it looked wrong 

python3 get_dimensions.py 
Screen width height diagonal
--------------------------------
DP-1-1 10.0 10.0 14.2

Comment: Hmm. I wish I could test on your resolution. Many things break on that. Are you using scaling? @aless80

Comment: No I don't think. If you like I have the outputs of xrandr and xdpyinfo, but from Sunday on I'll stay offline for some weeks

Comment: @agold: the source of this information ultimately comes from the monitor itself, retrieved from its [`EDID` data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)

Answer (score 27):

How'bout this :

`xrandr | awk '/ connected/{print sqrt( ($(NF-2)/10)^2 + ($NF/10)^2 )/2.54" inches"}'`

and through SSH :

`ssh server DISPLAY=:0 xrandr | awk '/ connected/{print sqrt( ($(NF-2)/10)^2 + ($NF/10)^2 )/2.54" inches"}'`

Comment: Precise and worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Works perfect one-liner.

Answer (score 18):

Just in case you want a more general answer, you can cut the [the gordian knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot), and use a non-geeky physical [ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruler) for that. As per [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_size), the "size of a screen is usually described by the length of its [diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal)":

[image]

If you have a ruler that only displays [centimeters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre), you can use the simple [conversion](https://www.google.de/search?q=centimeter+to+inch):

```
1 cm = 0.393701 in
(or 2.54 cm = 1 in)
```

So if your ruler measures *30 centimeters*, your screen is *11.811* inches. You can also use [google](http://google.com) with a query of the form `30 cm to in`.

---

Image credits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Display_size_measurements.png

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a site for Software solutions, so your answer is a bit off-topic here...  On the other hand, it's correct, well written, very readable and funny!  **:-)**  So upvoted!

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW: Actually, it's based on a mistake on my side. I read the question, "How can I get my laptop's monitor size?", and my first thought was "well, with a ruler", and before reading the complete question, I had my answer carved out the stone block.

Comment: As a side note, one inch equals 25.4 mm exactly.

Comment:  love that gordian knot reference 

Comment: @Fabby, as per info on the page I saw, the question is for "linux command" and was edited before that answer was given, so the answer is not correct.

Answer (score 8):

`Xdpyinfo` is a utility for displaying information about an X server.  It is used to examine the capabilities of a server, the predefined values for various parameters used in communicating between clients and the server, and the different types of screens and visuals that are available.

The command to get the monitor size is:

```
xdpyinfo | grep dimensions
```

Result

```
dimensions:    1366x768 pixels (361x203 millimeters)
```

Comment: Hi Parto, I really like your answer +1, however, look here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204823 there is a *huge* difference in the dimensions `xdpyinfo` reports and `xrandr`.

Comment: @Jacob Something interesting - http://askubuntu.com/questions/378386/how-to-get-the-right-dpi-resolution-on-ubuntu-13-04-saucy

Comment: When measuring with a good old physical quality tape-measure, I get on my screen pretty much exactly the output of `xrandr`: 473mm, while `xdpyinfo` reports *way* too short (`445mm`). This question turns out to be more interesting then OP assumed I guess :)

Comment: it is 2022 and it is still incorrect on my device.

Answer (score 0):

This was something that I too was struggling with(when I wanted to upgrade to a new monitor for myself and wanted to know what size my old monitor was), so I wrote a shell script that finds the monitor size for you.

I used the `xdpyinfo` from the first answer to get the screen dimensions and built ahead on it. The script essentially computes the diagonal from the screen dimensions, converting from millimeters to inches and displays the result.

Repository URL: https://github.com/abhishekvp/WhatsMyScreenSize

Hope this helps!