# understanding details of xrandr

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

while exploring different possibilities of my monitor with different resolutions I have been using `xrandr`. I wish to know what one of the outputted data of `xrandr` means.

In the following example I would like to know what the final data set means (the part stating 890mm x 500mm)

```
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 890mm x 500mm
```

What are these Dimensions specifically, and are these parameters changeable?

Comment: My guess is, its the mm size of the screen itself not the chassis.

Comment: @Videonauth - I get different ouputs of this parameter depending on the stauts of my monitor being turned off or on. ON=890mm x 500mm OFF=708mm x 398mm

Comment: Maybe a kind of default setting to go to when it doesnt get data from the monitor. Curious if the On measurements would fit to your monitor.

Comment: `xrandr` uses metric (mm) while `Ubuntu System Settings` shows monitor size in inches  (55")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What it means

In the line:

```
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 890mm x 500mm
```

indeed, the last section: `890mm x 500mm` gives you the size of your screen x/y in `mm`

#### Why the difference?

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736113/how-can-i-get-my-laptops-monitor-size/736118#736118), we ran into the same issue. The explanation is that by default, the screen is "assumed" to be at `96dpi`, which is not necessarily the case. If the screen is on, the value is set form the "real" resolution (pixels/inch), which is obviously slightly different on your screen.

[this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/589485) is related to the issue; you would probably get the same difference when getting the screen info via `xdpyinfo`. Note that the `xrandr`size with screen *on* is the correct size.

Obviously, you cannot change these values.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I tend to think not, since it is purely a "virrtual", informational rendering of the size. On the other hand, do you have a (set of) screenshots (before/after)? It would be interesting to measure if the changes are of the same ratio.

Comment: ok I was thinking the same thing, so I updated my answer on the other post, (included some more information about some buggy behavior), and also included the screenshots https://askubuntu.com/questions/742897/chrome-resolution-changes-when-monitor-is-turned-off