# How to set up Gnome interface for HiDPI screen?

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, dpi

I have a 3200x1800 ultrabook and I would like to decrease the resolution of the screen 2x. The problem is that once I do it all the GUI elements increase in size too much

[image]

Is there a way how to scale down the size of everything that Gnome Shell shows ?

Comment: What do you mean by decrease resolution ? You used a 1080p resolution ?

Comment: sorry for not being precise ... by the decrease I mean from 3200x1800 to 1920x1080

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your best bet is to keep the 3200x1800 resolution and just change the  interface scaling factor of GNOME.

## Command line method:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

You can  reset this setting later by running :

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor
```

---

## Graphical method:

You can use the `gnome-tweak-tool`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Go to "**Windows**" and set "**Window Scaling**" to **2**:

[image: gnome-tweak-tool screenshot]
<sup>Credit to [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com) for the screenshot</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this fixes the issue to some extent on my primary builtin 3200x1800 display.

However, once I connect a secondary one which has a native resolution of 1920x1080 the secondary display shows the same issue. Setting the scaling factor to a lower value doesnt really improve the situation.

Comment: [Screenshot of the current situation](http://i.imgur.com/n9xkdqT.png). The right part is the external display, the left is the builtin ultrabook display.

Comment: I tried to decrease the resolution of the primary display to the same resolution of the secondary and then setting the scaling-factor to a lower value but it seems that the scaling factor does not allow fractional values.

Comment: Please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-two-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screen)

Comment: THANKS! Although I have the gnome screen scaling bug the thread seems like a great resource.

Comment: reducing the sizes on the `lesser` display can be done with
````xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 2x2````

Comment: Neither of these options work on Ubuntu 17.10, in Gnome-Tweak-Tools there is no "Window scaling" option on this page (but others like in the above screenshot).

Comment: On my Ubuntu 17.10 I tried doing `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"` but it didn't add any settings. I didn't have an HDPI section in the tweak tool. The only thing that worked was `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2` after logging out and logging back in. _[Scaling-factor can only take integers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#GNOME)_

Comment: This was in Unity back then. In gnome, Window scaling is not enabled by default in Tweaks, so you missed a step. Also it will only work with integer factors like 2, not 1.5. Finally this is only possible for `gnome-shell` >= 3.30 which is NOT currently available for latest LTS (18.04), its still ... 3.28