# Lower DPI on external monitor?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display, gtk, hdpi

I have a 15 inch latptop with a 4K built-in display (3840x2160) connected to a 1440p external monitor (2560x1440). 
From the Display settings, I applied a **Scale for menu and title bars** of 2 on the built-in display and 1 on the external one.

From this point, the window contents is huge on my external monitor because I use **Scale all window contents to match: Display with largest controls**. Changing this settings makes windows content tiny and not readable.

Is there a way to have different window contents scale per display ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
xrandr
```

will show your available monitors and resolutions.
then use for example :

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1200 --fb 3840x4200 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1x1 --pos 320x2400
```

1. --output HDMI1 in this case is the external screen, eDP1 is the laptop screen.
2. --scale 2x2 - make everything on external screen twice smaller
3. --mode XxY - explicitly set the resolution for screen (not necessary if is already set)
4. --fb XxY - set size of a virtual screen (framebuffer) (important without this, you will be able to use only a fourth part of the
   screen). In my case one screen was on top of another, so I added up 
   effective heights 2400+1800=4200. Also note, that maximum
   framebuffer    size might be specified in xorg.conf - then you
   cannot exceed it (it     is written in the first line of xrandr -q
   output).
5. --pos XxY - in this case I set absolute positioning of the screens, so the laptop screen is directly on the bottom of the external sceen.

this guide found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-two-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screen). does it help ?