# Dual monitors and HiDPI display struggling to scale properly

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

Hello I have been trying to setup a second monitor for my laptop under Ubuntu 18.04 and I can't seem to be able to scale the second monitor properly.

My monitors are :

- XPS 15 4k built-in display (3840x2160)
- Dell 24" (2560x1440)

As most people using 4K resolution on a 15" display, I scaled the display to 200% using GNOME.
The issue comes from the fact that gnome cannot scale different displays in different ways. So when I hook up my other monitor I get a zoom to important on my 24" monitor.

Aster looking online for a while I tried using arandr to no avail and I then stumbled upon [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens).

It explains very well how to set up 2 displays using XrandR. Unfortunately It seems not to work for my problem.

Given that I want my second monitor on the left of my laptop screen and that my `xrandr -q` returns :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6400 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 526mm x 296mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1200     59.95  
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Here is what I tried :

```
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --scale 2x2 --fb 6400x2160 --pos 0x0
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --pos 2560x0
```

Unfortunatly here is what it gives:

```
xrandr: specified screen 6400x2160 not large enough for output DP-1-1 (5120x2880+0+0)
```

And I get my 2 displays overlapping.

It's really been messing with me lately so if any of you have any idea how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer Shinigami and for any other persons stumbling upon this thread, I did find a way to make it work.

What I ended up doing was set the DPI and the final size of both screen together:

```
xrandr --dpi 331 --fb 7424x2448
```

Followed by :

```
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --scale 1.7x1.7 --pos 0x0
```

and

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.8x0.8 --pos 4352x0
```

This is fine tuned to my problem but I can explain it more extensivly if anybody asks.

Answer (score 0):

use `arandr` to position your windows and scale using below commands

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 2x2 --mode 3840x2160  
xrandr --output DP1 --scale 1x1 --mode 2560x1440
```

installing `arandr`

```
aptitude install arandr
```

Answer (score 0):

> xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 2x2 --mode 3840x2160

Although it didn't seem quite right I tried it anyway and got this :

```
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 8192x8192 (desired size 10240x4320)
```

edit:

Just in case, if you meant

```
xrandr --output DP-1-1 --scale 2x2 --mode 2560x1440
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1 --mode 3840x2160
```

I tried it, the screen still overlapped and arandr didn't let me set them appart : 
[image]

Comment: did you solve it?