# Auto-scaling on HiDPI and normal DPI displays .... how?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, hdpi

I have Ubuntu 18.04LTS (with default Gnome and Cinnamon), my main display is 4K and external 1080p.
I have problem with most apps. they don't scale properly on external display - they stay double size (2x) which makes them barely usable.

Apps that scale properly are: **Gnome Terminal** and **Nemo** (didn't test others/many).

How to solve it ? Apps that i use currently and auto-scaling would be really useful (chrome,chromium,intellij IDEA)

Comment: You should be able to set scaling per display with xrandr command. Like here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have different DPI configurations for two different screens?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens)