# How to adjust DPI in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, lightdm, dpi

I [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437859/how-do-i-adjust-dpi-in-12-04) about fixing DPI in 12.04.

The [14.04 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Desktop) list "Support for High-DPI screens and desktop scaling."

Post upgrade, it seems that nothing has changed. Similar symptoms from [my previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437859/how-do-i-adjust-dpi-in-12-04) persist:

- The 1" square [here](http://www.infobyip.com/detectmonitordpi.php) is closer to 1/2"
- Despite the line `xserver-command=X -dpi 170` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, xdpyinfo reports 96x96 dpi

I did find that I was able to use the "Scale for menu and title bars" slider in System Settings>Displays to fix title bar text size instead of setting `org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi).

The last post also mentions that in Gnome 3, DPI is hard coded to 96. Is this a limitation in 14.04? (I am somewhat ignorant to the distinction between Gnome and Unity) Can I do anything to properly set my DPI?

Comment: I have a Macbook Pro Retina. As I don't care about ultra hd, what has worked for me is to set the resolution to 1440x900.

Answer (score 1):

The option "Scale for menu and title bars" should suffice, it's kind of badly named, it scales everything and not only menu and title bars. I'm using it on a 13.3'' 3200x1800 screen and it works.

The only thing you have to add to that is [an option in about:config in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487032/adjust-firefox-and-thunderbird-to-a-high-dpi-touchscreen-display-retina) (and Thunderbird if you use it)

Comment: If you have to adjust settings in other programs, it is not scaling _everything_. Perhaps it's scaling all of the system UI elements, but the question is about changing DPI system-wide.

Comment: @jake: It scales DPI system-wide, but Firefox ignores the system wide setting. Every other software that I've tried works.

Comment: @LeartS No it is not firefox's fault. Did you try eclipse? Netbeans? Chrome? Skype? Brackets? ...  Firefox in fact, does pretty good job, especially with the AutoHiDPI  addon.

Comment: Those are all applications that use their own toolkit and ignore what the underlying system tells them, i.e. "it's their fault". But a lot of them are rapidly adapting, for example Chrome, Chromium, Android Studio, PyCharm now all work by default