# Upgrade Ubuntu LTS to a Version that supports MacBook retina

Tags: gnome, kernel, macbook-pro, dpi

I have Ubuntu LTS 14.04 with Gnome 3 as GUI installed on my MacBook ( *it's a persent* ) and some things don not work very well. Like Chromium is eye hurting small and my thunderbold interfaces do not work very well either.

I know that for Thunderbold support i would need at least Kernel 3.14 but my current Kernel is 3.13.something.
I also know that for Gnome to work with HiDPI desktops it'll need Gnome 3.12 but 3.10 is installed.

So my question is, what can i do to get newer Software while beeing aware that it is not that tested and might break.

Comment: I have a Macbook Pro Retina and Ubuntu 14.04 works flawlessly! No problems with Thunderbolt. BTW, what problems are you having? The only thing that doesn't work is the camera, but there's no support for that on Linux in general. For High-DPI  see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/513581/how-to-adjust-dpi-in-14-04).

Comment: About the camera, there is a launchpad bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1276811) and also, an upstream bug [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71131). Since the bug affects you, you may wish to vote for it to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To update your kernel you can use a guide like: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds (but you could just google for it)

**Installing upstream kernels**

To boot into an upstream kernel you only need to download and install the *image*.deb package that corresponds to your architecture. In addition, if you need to build any external modules you also need the correspinding headers-_.deb and headers-_all.deb packages.

For example, let us use http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.4-utopic/. 
If you were testing i386, you would want those marked A. 
If you were testing amd64, B. 
(Use generic kernel unless you have a special need for lowlatency kernel, such as audio production.)

B  linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_amd64.deb

A  linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_i386.deb

linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-lowlatency_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_amd64.deb

linux-headers-3.14.4-031404-lowlatency_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_i386.deb

AB linux-headers-3.14.4-031404_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_all.deb

B  linux-image-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_amd64.deb

A  linux-image-3.14.4-031404-generic_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_i386.deb

linux-image-3.14.4-031404-lowlatency_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_amd64.deb

linux-image-3.14.4-031404-lowlatency_3.14.4-031404.201405130853_i386.deb

Once you have those downloaded they will need to be installed using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

When this process completes you should have a new entry on your boot menu representing the upstream kernel. This will appear as an entry like this:

```
Ubuntu Trusty, kernel 3.14.4-031404-generic
```

**Updating Gnome to 3.12:**

This step is taking from: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-gnome-3-12-on-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-trusty-tahr/

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install bijiben polari gnome-clocks gnome-weather gnome-maps gnome-music gnome-photos gnome-documents gnome-contacts epiphany-browser gnome-sushi gnome-boxes gnome-shell-extensions
```

Now you should logout and log back in to Gnome 3.12.

Comment: Well thanks a lot Dan, I need could have found this all by myself. I just thought there would be an easier way. But it looks like I have to take the long road. I'll give that a try ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for chromium (or google chrome for that matter):

```
$ chromium --high-dpi-support=1 --force-device-scale-factor=2
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

About the DPI part, you can also try "normal" Ubuntu (Ubuntu Unity) which will have high DPI support by default (no need to use PPA or any other package).