# How to change DPI in Ubuntu GNOME 14.04?

Tags: gnome, vmware, install-from-source, ubuntu-gnome, dpi

What I would like to do is "Change DPI to 144 in Ubuntu GNOME 14.04".

Because it's first time to me to use linux, I installed VMware Player in my laptop,
and I installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.04.
My laptop has 1920x1080 in 11.6 inch display, so I use 144 dpi for Windows 8.1 which is host of VMware, but in Ubuntu GNOME, letters become really small.

At first, I have tried to use Gnome-Tweak-Tool to change the text scaling factor. It changes font sizes in title bars, menus, etc, but not for some application's content. (e.g. firefox)

So, I use MSN to google the other way, and it tells me that in GNOME, dpi size is written in the source code of gnome-setting-deamon.

[plugins/xsettings/gsd-xsettings-manager.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/xsettings/gsd-xsettings-manager.c#L231)
`#define DPI_FALLBACK 96`

Thus I have tried the commands bellow.

```
$ mkdir source
$ cd source
$ apt-get source gnome-settings-deamon
$ cd gnome-settings-daemon-3.8.6.1
```

and replace the row to `#define DPI_FALLBACK 144`.

**What should I do next to reflect to this change for my system?**

I'm not sure that I have a collect way or not, so if it's wrong, please tell me the right way.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check out: 
[How to adjust DPI in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513581/how-to-adjust-dpi-in-14-04)

What you did was download the source for gnome-settings-daemon, and edit the config from that source. This doesn't affect anything since the things in your source folder aren't used by your system. It would only work if you compiled it and overwrote the relevant files in your system, but don't do that since it would probably break many things and is bad practice - it's a bad way of configuring things. If you really wanted to configure stuff in Linux, it's best you use configuration files.

An example of config file (but this is most likely not what you want to fix your DPI problem): https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en#daemonconfig

Comment: Thank you for answering.  
Well, I've checked out that topic, and I've created `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, but that doesn't change anything.  
I have also changed "Scale for menu and title bars", but it doesn't change sizes of some applications, like firefox.  
Some pages say that gnome shell overwrite the dpi settings by gnome-setting-deamon, that's why I am trying to compile the source.  
So if you know another way that works, please tell me. thanks.

Comment: Did you try changing the parameter in about:config for firefox? 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/487032/adjust-firefox-and-thunderbird-to-a-high-dpi-touchscreen-display-retina

Comment: Yes, I did it. but it only changes firefox's contents area size. Not for address bar or other tools.  
What I need is change all tools size, not just for firefox.
So that doesn't work for me.