# HDTV recognized as 7-inch screen causes wrong DPI settings

Tags: 14.04, resolution, dpi, hdtv

I just finished building myself a Ubuntu HTPC/Home server, and when I was setting it up, it was hooked to a 24" ASUS monitor using HDMI, no problem there, crystal clear image. But now that it's ready to roll, I've moved it to my TV (42" LG HDTV), still using HDMI for A/V link.

Here's my problem : my TV is identified by Ubuntu as a 7" screen, so the DPI is all messed up. I've tried looking online, and most people say it's an overscan issue, but I can still see all of the screen, it's just scaled terribly wrong :

[image]

Here's my setup :

- MB : Asus H87M-E C2
- CPU : Intel Pentium G3440
- GPU : Integrated Intel HD Graphics
- RAM : 4 Go DDR3

My question is : how can I fix the screen detection ? And if it's not possible, is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi) going to work ?

I am fairly new to the UNIX world, and I don't really know my way around things other than the basic terminal commands, so please dumb it down for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many research, this appears to be a bug in GNOME 3. [This link](http://www.redips.net/linux/gnome-wrong-window-scaling-tv/) offers a workaround, and while it's not perfectly sized, it's still an improvement from the previous scaling