# Okular doesn't show correct zoom factors (too small)

Tags: okular, zooming

Okular's view/zoom sizes are too small.
When I set the zoom size to 100% the display of a document is smaller than the original size. I estimated a value of approximately 128% to show documents at a real 100% size.
This issue has been unchanged throughout all updates of the recent half year (*I just started working with (K)Ubuntu then*).

Other programs (e.g. LibreOffice, PDFmod, PDFsam) do show documents at 100% zoom with a real 100% size.

I have two monitors connected with no difference in this effect.

*System:* Kubuntu 14.04, KDE 4.13.3, Linux (x86_64) release 3.16.0-71-generic;
*Okular:* 0.19.3

If someone could help on this issue, it would easy my life a little bit, because clicking and entering each time "128+[ENTER]" is meanwhile shattering my nerves. <:-[

Thank you.

Comment: What are the DPI of your monitor and what the relative settings in Kubuntu?

Comment: As far as I can say, it's not set. So I presume it's all the default settings (96DPI). Does it make a difference in different applications?

Comment: in theory no, it doesn't. But it might be (one never knows for sure until the culprit is found). So, what is the real DPI of your monitor? See http://askubuntu.com/a/272172/29595

Comment: Ok, interesting article.
I've calculated my real DPI with ~ 95,6 DPI. 
So, if I set this value to 100%, the system setting of 96 DPI is ~100.42% which does not explain the ~128% that I measured in Okular to fit real 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with Evince (the PDF viewer for GNOME and Unity systems) and some other applications. The issue can be solved by explicitly telling your (physical) display size to the X server.

Create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-monitor.conf` and add the following content:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "<default monitor>"
    DisplaySize 294 165    # In millimeters
EndSection
```

You have to change the numerical values and you might also need to tweak the identifier if you have more than one monitor.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer :) But I'd like to know before if this could have an effect on ALL applications. Recently I finally was able to solve a refresh rate issue (on CRT w/ 2nd TFT) after **7 months** of searching, on which I had to modify my xorg.conf. I REALLY don't want to loose/override these settings as I can actually only see this effect in Okular. . _(It took me much too long time to solve this.)_

Comment: You won't need to edit `/etc/xorg.conf`, but `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-monitor.conf` which is an override to the current configuration. The `DisplaySize` parameter does not alter the refresh rate.

Comment: @Jens: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. I tried your tip but it worked just for this percentage problem. Unfortunately it messed up all my other metrics so I decided not to use it and – sorry – then I forgot to give my feedback here. I guess it would work out better when I adjust these other metrics. Maybe I'll try it later, after I exchanged some other components. So **thank you very much** for helping :-)