# Display is on 42" TV

Tags: hdmi, display-resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

- On Intel® Desktop Board DH55TC
- With Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
- 500 GB SATA hard drive
- **Connected to 42" LG TV with HDMI cable**
- TP-Link 300 MB USB wireless LAN
- Wireless keyboard & mouse

All drivers are installed properly, display is also nice looking as per the TV. All is working fine.

As display is on 42" TV and I am seating far, I cannot read. Is there any utility which can make screen more readable and we can work from far or any kind of work around.

Comment: Is the problem the _clarity_ of the text, or the _size_ of the text?

Comment: size of the text.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite simple actually - find the "Displays" utiltity in the dash,and drag the "Scale for menus and titlebars" slider to the right, which will make everything bigger:

[image]

Another possibility would be to lower the resolution, which would also make things bigger on-screen. A third possibility may be to change the DPI, but that's [somewhat complicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi).

([Credits to Luis Alvarado for the screenshot](https://askubuntu.com/a/462023/383125))