# How to adjust zoom scale in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, scale-mode

When I go into LibreOffice writer and hold up a page to a screen, it is not the same size.

If I change the zoom to 117% they are the same size.

How do I scale the page size (and not the rest of the LibreOffice UI) so that 117% zoom would be shown as 100%?

**How I did it:**
First, I calculated the new DPI: `Current DPI/100*Scale`, in my case it was `96/100*117=112.32`. I then rounded down the resulting number (`112`). Then I went into the 'Startup Applications' setting and added this command: `xrandr --dpi 112`. Then I logged out, then went back in again to verify my settings were correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to **adjust the dpi settings on OS level**. There are different approaches how to do this, they are explained in some answers to "[*How to find and change the screen DPI?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/197828/20661)".

Comment: I don't think it's the DPI setting. Adjusting it from 96 makes everything huge (compared to my other computer)

Comment: Hmm - i'm really not sure - i supposed LO's 100% to be relative to the dpi setting. Sad to hear this doesn't work...

Comment: Update: I found it _was_ the DPI setting, and I adjusted the wrong setting.

Comment: @luk3yx: great :-) - and thanks for sharing your solution - it may be helpful for other users, too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a way to do this, but you can set your measurements to mm/cm/inches or others and base your formatting around that.

You can add a vertical ruler by enabling it: settings: -> tools -> options -> LibreOffice Writer -> View -> Vertical ruler

Comment: I know about the built-in ruler, and it is on. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have two monitors, they may have different DPI value. It might be non-obvious if the values aren't drastically different like HiDPI vs normal monitor.

I, in particular, have a 1280 × 1024 monitor with 377mm × 300mm dimensions, which gives 86 DPI, to which the X server's DPI setting is set. But my second monitor is 1920 × 1080 with 477mm × 268mm dimensions, thus having 102 DPI.

This difference results in the virtual sheet matching the paper sheet in size on one monitor but not on the other. So be sure to set X server's DPI setting to the one of the monitor where you're going to display your LibreOffice Writer windows.