# How to handle HiDiPi / retina screens of different sizes

Tags: firefox, fonts, display-resolution, hdpi

I'm working on a Thinkpad T480s, which has a WQHD (2560x1440) 14" display.  This makes for very small fonts in Firefox and the window manager (Xfce).

In principle, I *could* set the `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` setting in Firefox and manually set the window manager font size etc.  *However*, I also have a 27" WQHD external monitor.  And this means that all these settings (window manager, Firefox) would make the fonts good on one but bad on the other screen.

So my question seems to be the following: *How can I set different DPI values for my different screens, and have all applications (i.e., Firefox) respect these?*

I should add that apparently, there once was a AutoHiDPI extension for Firfox, but it seems to be gone and I cannot find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find and change the screen DPI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi). Almost all of the answers there deal with changing it monitor-wise.